# What is the removeDuplicates(ar) sub method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

**Code :**

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String []args) {
        int[] ar={54,67,98,12,43,58,91,98,29,99,54,61};
        int[] newArray=removeDuplicates(ar);
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));//[54,67,98,12,43,58,91,98,29,99,54,61]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));//[54,67,98,12,43,58,91,29,99,61]
    }
}
```

I want that what is the sub-method for this code in Java.

Comment: In its current form, the question is too broad. Please [edit] the post and add a focused questoin.

Comment: What about something simple as `Arrays.stream(ar).distinct().toArray()`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove duplicates from the array:

```
 public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] a){
   return Arrays.stream(a).distinct().toArray();
}
```

Comment: This answre uses javasciprt, OP is in java.

Comment: Can I know the what is the submehtod for this

Comment: [The code does not compile](https://ideone.com/rr4kBY). --- I heavily recommend to not remove the optional `{` and `}` around the one-line body of the loop. This can be a nasty bug.

Comment: @Turing85 Agree thanks, This can be a nasty bug. I've made some more edits to make this 
[work](https://ideone.com/6Dze3N)

Comment: Not really. Specification is to return an `int[]`. The code provided returns an `Integer[]`.

Comment: in that case. :/

Comment: If already using streams ... why also throw in a linked hash set and a for-each loop? Simply do `return Arrays.stream(ar).distinct().toArray()`, that's it.

Comment: Awesome @Seelenvirtuose didn't knew about it. Thanks. I've edited the answer